# Fr/En differences in the use of autres/other, or in the way that modifiers combine

Tags: usage

In the terminology of the European Union, a non-member state is referred to as *un état tiers*.

Spain and Italy are, of course, members of the EU.

With that in mind, would it be correct to refer to *un accord entre l'Espagne, l'Italie et d'autres états tiers*?

For comparison *an agreement between Spain, Italy and other third states* means *an agreement between Spain, Italy and other states which, like Spain and Italy, are third states*. It cannot mean *an agreement between Spain, Italy and other states which are third states*.

Is there a difference between French and English here, or is the French sentence just careless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that context, the sentence is legit if one or more non EU states have already been mentioned like in:

> *La France et l'Allemagne ont conclu un accord avec la Suisse. Il y aura probablement aussi un accord entre l'Espagne, l'Italie et d'autres États tiers.*

i.e. *d'autres États tiers que la Suisse.*

Comment: Thanks. I am sure that the intended meaning was états autres que l'Espagne ou l'Italie, so I think it must have been a slip. What do you think of je suis allé au câfé de la place avec Jean et deux autres de nos amis?

Comment: *Je suis allé au café de la place avec Jean et deux autres de nos amis* means the third and fourth persons are friends with both me and either the person I'm talking to or some other person/group already mentioned. Otherwise, that would have been *je suis allé au café de la place avec Jean et deux autres de mes amis.*

Comment: Thanks. Would *Je suis allé au café de la place avec Jean et deux de nos amis* be likely, and would it imply that Jean himself is not a friend of mine (we can assume that nobody else has been mentioned)?

Comment: Likely. Jean is not part of the set *nos amis* but who is behind *no(u)s* is not explicit. That can be either me and the person I'm talking, me and Jean, or even the three of us. Jean can still be a friend of mine if he belongs the person I'm talking to's family. Jean might also be my brother, my cousin, my husband...